# Problemas con el posicionamiento del footer

Tags: html, jquery, css

Necesito acomodar el footer siempre al pie de pagina pero no funciona como lo estoy haciendo

```css
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #464d51;
    text-align: center;
    color: #8c969c;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrias agregar todo tu css estilo

Comment: El problema es que debes asignar tus contenedores al 100% de la pagina, podría mostrarte en un ejemplo, pero tendrías que cambiar el HTML de tu pagina.

Comment: Probaste con position:fixed; ?

Comment: El position:fixed haría que siempre se vea en la pantalla, así el contenido sea más grande que ella. No sería una buena solución.

Answer (score 2):

El problema lo tienes en el código html. Debes de tener abierta o mal posicionada alguna etiqueta. Tambien es importante separar el contenido con contenedores `<div></div>` para que no de estos fallos.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo rápido que he creado con una tabla:

```css
 body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        #contenedorPrincipal {
            background-color: aqua;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        
        table,
        table tr th,
        table tr td {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: white;
        }
        
        footer {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            position: bottom;
        }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
    <main>
        <div id="contenedorPrincipal">
            <h1>Contenedor principal con el contenido de tu pagina.</h1>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jill</td>
                    <td>Smith</td>
                    <td>50</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Eve</td>
                    <td>Jackson</td>
                    <td>94</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <div>
            Contenido del footer
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

A lo que quieres hacer se le llama Sticky Footer y [aquí](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/) puedes encontrar una guía de las diferentes maneras de implementarlo.

Espero que sea de ayuda. Un saludo.